# How can we play YouTube Videos now with iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm taking a course online that shows how to play videos from a url. But it's always the [bunny one](https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4). I've been looking how to play YouTube videos, been finding that they use to use UIWebView. Since it's been deprecated, how would I be able to play them now. This is how my code looks like.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class CourseDetailVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

    var course: Courses.Course?

    @IBAction func playURLVideo() {
        guard let videoURL = URL(string: course?.videoUrl ?? "") else { return }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }
```

I just have a button. When I press it I would like to play a YouTube video. Now this works with the bunny one. How would I be able to play this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1roy4o4tqQM).

### Screenshot after button is press

[image]

### Updated Code

```
 @IBAction func playButtonPress() {
    // Create Video player
    var mywkwebview: WKWebView?
    let mywkwebviewConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    mywkwebviewConfig.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    mywkwebview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: mywkwebviewConfig)

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JePnQ1gSagc?playsinline=1?autoplay=1")
    let youtubeRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

    mywkwebview?.load(youtubeRequest)

    guard let webView = mywkwebview else { return }
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

}
```

Comment: The documentation for UIWebView tells you what to use in its place.

Comment: use this https://github.com/malkouz/youtube-ios-player-helper-swift

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution to `WKWebView`

Since YouTube has functionality to load any video in fullscreen in a webview without any of the scrolling features using a URL in the format `https://www.youtube.com/embed/<videoId>`.

The given video above has an ID of `(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1roy4o4tqQM)` -- `[1roy4o4tqQM]`

```
mywkwebviewConfig.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
mywkwebview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: mywkwebviewConfig)
let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1roy4o4tqQM?playsinline=1?autoplay=1")
var youtubeRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
mywkwebview.load(youtubeRequest)
```

### Updated code:

```
@IBAction func playURLVideo() {

  var mywkwebview: WKWebView?
  let mywkwebviewConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()

  mywkwebviewConfig.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
  mywkwebview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: mywkwebviewConfig)

  let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1roy4o4tqQM?playsinline=1?autoplay=1")
  var youtubeRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

  mywkwebview.load(youtubeRequest)
}
```

You need to add `?autoplay=1` to the end of the embed `URL`

Comment: How would you be able to play the video automatic?

Comment: What do you mean “automatic”?

Comment: Like the AVPlayerViewController when you allow player to play. ex: plaverViewController.player.play(). So when I click the button, the video plays in full screen.

Comment: check the screenshot. It shows what happens in after I press the button. I'm trying to play the video when the button is click and in fullscreen. Would it be possible?

Comment: Aha, you're trying to use AutoPlay. check the new code:

Comment: Doesn't autoplay still, why?

Comment: Hmm. So I tried it with 3 other videos, still have me press the YouTube button to play the video. Check the updated code.

Comment: I’m a full time code mentor and I’d like to look into this for you. If it’s okay. Can you hit me up on Skype(rawandahmad10@outlook.com) I’ll be definitely solving this problem right away.

Comment: Don't have a Skype. So is there another way to contact you? Cause I can't even move this to a chat not enough reputation. Or should I just wait for your answer here. Thanks for taking the time to help me with my problem.

Comment: No it’s okay. I could use email. Contact the email. And if it’s possible attach your project. I’ll look into it and solve it my way; using AVPlayer.

Comment: Let me know if you got it

Comment: Got it; will reply really soon. Appreciate the patience